# Data URIs -- is it possible to have multiple formats overlapping?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate, data-uri

Let's say I had a background gif like this:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7
```

And an SVG:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 50 50'
%3e%3cpath d='M22 38V51L32 32l19-19v12C44 26 43 10 38 0 52 15 49 39 22 38z'/%3e
%3c/svg%3e
```

And I wanted to put the SVG in front of the GIF, but do it all in one data URI. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Data URLs generally represent single files, but your concantenation will neither be a valid GIF file nor a valid SVG file.

Comment: Have the gif as an image in the SVG file.

Comment: @SuperStormer For creating NFTs, especially one's with backgrounds that will be updated.

Comment: The problem of only being able to display one image at a time is often solved by using an HTML page (lol). But in this case where one of the files is a SVG the GIF could just be part of the SVG like @RobertLongson suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you, Robert, for the suggestion--embedding the image into the SVG. I also needed to add in 'xmlns:xlink' info.

```
data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 100 100'> <image xlink:href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/VAN_CAT.png/440px-VAN_CAT.png' width='100' height='100' /> %3cpath d='M22 38V51L32 32l19-19v12C44 26 43 10 38 0 52 15 49 39 22 38z' stroke='red'/%3e %3c/svg>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The inner image must itself be a data url.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the feedback. Could you clarify what you mean by it not working? When I copy and paste that code into my browser, I can see both the SVG and background image.

Comment: The browser's url bar is somewhat special and unrestricted. Try an image element or using it as a background image and you'll see the problem.